# GAE Storing Key vs StringID

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, key, app-engine-ndb

Are there advantages to storing Keys over String in Google App Engine datastore.

For example:

```
class Model(ndb.Model):
    user_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
```

VS

```
class Model(ndb.Model):
    user_id = ndb.StringProperty()
```

- Why would you want to store a Key instead of the StringID? Is it only for convenience?
- Which uses less storage space?
- Which is faster to query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using [entity groups](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities.html#Ancestor_Paths) (ancestors), the KeyProperty will support that.  When storing the id, unless the model who's id you're storing is the entity group root, you'll need to store enough info reconstruct the full key.

The KeyProperty will take more space, since it is storing additional data, but it may be more convenient to use when retrieving the other entity.  Query speed should be comparable.

Comment: Good point, with entity groups, storing the key makes more sense. With something simple like a User_id would you recommend storing the key or an string/int id?

Comment: I'd personally say it is your preference.  I like to store the key if there is any chance that you *might* want to use entity groups _or_ namespaces.  With something like user that is unlikely to ever change, the key name/id might well be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I had forgotten about namespaces. Also the keys storage of appid will make things simpler once Google allows sharing of data between applications.